# GTK code hangs @ gtk_container_add when called from thread

Tags: c, gtk, glib

AM very new to GTK and GLIB
i am just trying to display a image and then call a disptext function. 
but when the disptextpage function is called from main directly it works but when i create a thread  can call disptextpage it gets stuck in

```
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), textv);
```

and never comes back.
what is the error that i am commiting

please guide : below is the sample code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <glib.h>
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>
    //#include "dispimage.h"
    #include <windows.h>
    #define sleep(n) Sleep(1000 * n)
    GtkWidget* window;
    void dispInit(int argc, char* argv[]);
    void dispInfoPage(char* fileName, int duration);


    gpointer main_callback(gpointer data)
    {
        gtk_main();
        return 0;
    }

    void dispInit(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        gdk_threads_init();
        gdk_threads_enter();
        printf("Initializing the display library\n");
        gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
        window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
        gtk_window_resize(GTK_WINDOW(window), 640, 480);
        gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 640, 480);
        gtk_widget_realize( window );
        gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);
        g_thread_create(main_callback, NULL, FALSE, NULL);
        gdk_threads_leave();
    }

    void dispInfoPage(char* fileName, int duration)
    {
        int index;
        gdk_threads_enter();
        printf("Initializing dispInfoPage\n");
        destroyWidget();
        printf("Initializing dispInfoPage1\n");
        GtkWidget *image;
        image = gtk_image_new_from_file(fileName);
        printf("Initializing dispInfoPage2\n");
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), image);
        gtk_widget_show(image);
        gtk_widget_show(window);
        printf("Initializing dispInfoPage4\n");
        printf("Initializing dispInfoPage5\n");
        gdk_threads_leave();
        printf("Initializing dispInfoPage6\n");
    }

    void destroyWidget()
    {
        GList *children, *iter;
        struct WidgetsAlive *temp, *prev, *next, *depTemp;
        children = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(window));
        for(iter = children; iter != NULL; iter = g_list_next(iter)){
            gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(window),GTK_WIDGET(iter->data));
            printf("Deleting Widget\n");
        }
        g_list_free(iter);
        g_list_free(children);

    }


    int dispTextPage(char* fileName, int isJustifyCenter)
    {
        int index;
        GtkWidget *textv;
        GdkWindow *textv_window;
        GdkPixmap *pixmap = NULL;
        GtkTextBuffer *textBuffer;
        gdk_threads_enter();
        GdkColor color;
        char debugBuf[128] = { '\0' };
        char newfName[100]={'\0'};
        char ext[4]={'\0'};
        char temp[100]={'\0'};
        int i;
        FILE * fd;
        destroyWidget();
        textBuffer = gtk_text_buffer_new(NULL);
        textv = gtk_text_view_new_with_buffer(textBuffer);
        gtk_text_view_set_left_margin(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv), 22);
        gtk_text_view_set_right_margin(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv), 20);
        gtk_text_view_set_pixels_above_lines(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv),1);
        gtk_text_view_set_wrap_mode(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv), GTK_WRAP_CHAR);
        if (isJustifyCenter == 1)
        {
            gtk_text_view_set_justification(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv), GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER);
        }
        else
        {
            gtk_text_view_set_justification(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv), GTK_JUSTIFY_LEFT);
        }
        gtk_text_view_set_editable(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv), FALSE);
        gtk_text_view_set_cursor_visible(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv), FALSE);
        printf("tttt0");
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), textv);
        printf("tttt1");
        textv_window = gtk_text_view_get_window (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (textv),
                                               GTK_TEXT_WINDOW_TEXT);
        gdk_color_parse ("#68604d", &color);
        pixmap = gdk_pixmap_create_from_xpm ((GdkDrawable *) textv_window, NULL,
                                           &color, fileName);
        gdk_window_set_back_pixmap (textv_window, pixmap, FALSE);
        g_object_unref(pixmap);

        textBuffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv));

        gtk_text_buffer_create_tag (textBuffer, "Red", "foreground", "Red", NULL);
        gtk_text_buffer_create_tag (textBuffer, "RedBold","foreground", "Red",NULL);
          gtk_text_buffer_create_tag(textBuffer, "gray_bg", "background", "gray", NULL);
          gtk_text_buffer_create_tag(textBuffer, "italic",  "style", PANGO_STYLE_ITALIC, NULL);
          gtk_text_buffer_create_tag(textBuffer, "bold","weight", PANGO_WEIGHT_BOLD, NULL);
        gtk_text_buffer_create_tag (textBuffer, "RedFontWeight", "weight", 1000,NULL);
        gtk_text_buffer_create_tag (textBuffer, "RedBoldFontWeight","weight", 1000,NULL);
        gtk_widget_show(textv);
        gtk_widget_show(window);
        gdk_threads_leave();
        return index;
    }

    void *fsmThread_RunFunction()
    {
        int pollMsgRetVal = -1;
        printf("Now enter into for image");
        dispInfoPage("../images/givefp.gif",1);
        sleep(5);
        dispInfoPage("../images/bootup.gif",1);
        sleep(5);
        dispInfoPage("../images/givefp.gif",1);
        sleep(5);
        dispInfoPage("../images/bootup.gif",1);
        sleep(5);
        printf("Now enter into for disptext");
        dispTextPage("",0);
        printf("Now exit for disptext");
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        GThread *fsmThreadId;
        GError *error = NULL;
        g_thread_init(NULL);
        dispInit(argc, argv);
        dispInfoPage("../images/bootup.gif",1);
        sleep(5);
        printf("Now creat ethread ");
        fsmThreadId = g_thread_create(fsmThread_RunFunction,NULL,TRUE,&error);
        if (error) {
          fflush(stderr);
          exit(1);
        }
        g_thread_join(fsmThreadId);
        sleep(2);

        printf("ENd of main");
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All UI operations/functions may only be called from one thread**. This is a common API usage requirement for almost all (all I know of) UI libraries (Gtk+, Qt, wxWidgets...)

Just don't do it. Use worker threads, use `g_idle_add` or `g_timeout_add` and do the (timly short) UI modifications there.

Comment: :what is the best method for communicating between cross threads

Comment: @Ragav He already mentioned it: typically you would use `g_idle_add()` from the non-main threads.

Comment: `g_idle_add` in combination with `g_async_queue_push/pop` (the latter might not be needed, depends on your problem and how you implement it)

Comment: @drahnr thanks :: g_idle_add ::  was very much helpful and now checking the best way for arguments handling...